# create ng-model dynamically in ng-repeat and child ng-repeat using $index and $parent.$index?

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have form controllers with some input fields and checkbox when i click save and add another item button I am copying(clone) the entire form controllers at one time. It can be done n number of times. I am creating one array push the form elements when i click the button

```
 <div class="row category-description-block" ng-repeat="values in categoryval.CategoryValuesArray track by $index">
            <div class="col">
                <h3>Tell us about your jewelry</h3>
                <div class="list">
           <div class="form_group">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Type of Jewelry?
                            </div>
                              <span class="input-label"></span>
                            <input ng-model="categoryval.Luxary_Eyeware_Brand[$index]" type="text" placeholder="">
                        </label>
                    </div>




                    <!-- more details about jewelry starts -->
                <ion-checkbox ng-model="categoryval.jewelrymoreDetailschecked[$index]" ng-change="jewelrymoreDetailsChange($index)">I have the jewelry details
                        <br/> (Diamond shape, clarity, color, etc.)</ion-checkbox>

                    <div ng-show="IsVisible[$index]">

                        <div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h4>Describe your diamonds</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="repeat-set card">
                                <!-- inner repeating div strats-->

                                <div class="repeat-div" ng-repeat="jewels in categoryval.moreJewelryDetailsArray track by $index">
                                    <div class="row close-icon-bg">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <a href="" ng-model="jewels.closeItem[$parent.Sindex][$index]" ng-click="removeItem($parent.$index,$index)" class="close-icon">remove</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row ">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form_group">
                                                <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                                                    <span class="input-label">Quantity </span>
                                                    <input ng-model="jewels.quantity[$parent.$index][$index]" type="text" placeholder="Quantity">
                                                </label>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- inner repeating div Ends-->



                                <div class="form_group text-center">
                                    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                                        <button class="button button-small button-royal" ng-click="addJewelryDetails($index)">Add an additional item</button>
                                    </label>
                                </div>


                    <div class="form_group">
                        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                            <span class="input-label">Description</span>
                            <textarea ng-model="categoryval.description[$index]" placeholder=""></textarea>
                            <p class="form-notes">The more information you provide, the better!</p>
                        </label>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row custom-button">
            <div class="col-25">
                <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="categoryContinue(categoryval)">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="globalAppend()">Save and add another item</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the form controller inside I have the checkbox when i click check box there is one form-input field called quantity and Add another Item button.You can use this to create n number of quantity.I am using one more ng-repeat to push the values in to another array.

```
 $scope.addJewelryDetails = newJewelryDetails;
$scope.globalAppend = newGlobalDiv;


$scope.IsVisible = [];
$scope.categoryval = {
    jewelrymoreDetailschecked: false
};

$scope.jewelrymoreDetailsChange = function(index) {
    $scope.IsVisible[index] = $scope.categoryval.jewelrymoreDetailschecked[index];

};


$scope.categoryContinue = function(categoryvalues) {
    console.log(categoryvalues);
};



       $scope.categoryval = {};
     // $scope.categoryval.jewelryCollection = {};
    $scope.categoryval.images = [];
     $scope.categoryval.CategoryValuesArray = [];
      $scope.categoryval.moreJewelryDetailsArray = [];
      $scope.categoryval.quantity = [];

function init() {

    newJewelryDetails();
    newGlobalDiv();
}

function newGlobalDiv() {

    $scope.categoryval.CategoryValuesArray.push({});
}

function newJewelryDetails(parentindex) {

    $scope.categoryval.moreJewelryDetailsArray.push({});
    $scope.quantity = '';

}
$scope.removeItem = function(parentindex,index) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(parentindex));

   $log.log("parent Index:::" + parentindex + "index::::" +  index);


  //var quantity =       $scope.categoryval.moreJewelryDetailsArray[index].quantity;     
   $scope.categoryval.moreJewelryDetailsArray.splice(index,1);

};  


init();
```

but I have an issue on quantity field add and remove. for Example Parent1 have 3 Quantities field and parent2 have 3 quantities . Each parent have independent quantities. when I remove the second quantity from parent2 it will be remove from parent 1 also. I want to only remove on the parent 2 and parent1 individually and also add the quantiy fields. My complete working fiddle is here [codepen](http://codepen.io/techpalani/pen/PGKLLR/). Any one giving solution for me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use mutlidimensional arrays for this kind of logic.
Javascript/Json has the perfect type for this job.

You should have a jewelry array containing a list of items:

```
[
  {
    items: [{name: "", description: ""}, {name: "", description: ""}]
  },
  {
    items: [{name: "", description: ""}, {name: "", description: ""}]
  }
]
```

You remove items the same way:

```
$scope.removeItem = function(parentindex,index) {
   $scope.jewelryArray[parentIndex].items.splice(index,1);
};
```

Proof of concept: https://plnkr.co/edit/PLTFDvHszXrTWA7rrjcf?p=preview

EDIT: Complete plunker as per the comments.

https://plnkr.co/edit/crLzfRKFA2FrhRhXLcGY?p=preview

Comment: so I want to create two arrays for parent and child right ? can u give example fiddle

Comment: @Ben10 I added a plunker

Comment: so every form fields to create as a array like type of jewelry as array and also quantity as an array right?

Comment: @Ben10 yes, except quantity. Quantity should be the size of the array or a property of your object. items: [{name: "", description: "", quantity: 123}, {name: "", description: "", quantity: 51}]

Comment: how to define ng-model value?

Comment: @Ben10 For what element of the form? For the item name in my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9S2CppLw3TRGbGRIHuwD?p=preview

Comment: i have little confusion. how to push the values into this array and also define how to add quantity values

Comment: @Ben10: look at this: https://plnkr.co/edit/crLzfRKFA2FrhRhXLcGY?p=preview

Comment: can u explain based on my demo.I am creating ng-model based on $index and $parent.$index

Comment: How to add the quantiy field in this method

Comment: can you pls tell how to set the quantity value

Comment: Ben, just add a property quantity to your object just like I did with name... Can you try it and ask a different question if it doesn't work. Your original issue has been addressed already.